# Angular Interceptor test with a promise failing

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, jasmine, observable

I am having an issue with a unit test for one of my Interceptors whereas I get the following error when the test is run.

```
You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Here is my Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpBase } from "../http-base";
import { HttpUrl } from "../http-url.enum";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private httpBase: HttpBase
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (!this.isMiddleTierRequest(request.url)) {
            return next.handle(request);
        }

        this.httpBase.retrieveAuthToken()
            .then((token) => {
                const requestWithAuth = request.clone({ 
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }});

                    return next.handle(request);
            });
    }

    private isMiddleTierRequest(url: string): boolean {
        return url.indexOf(HttpUrl.MiddleTier) != -1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, any request is checked to see if it has a certain string match in it and if so a token is added to in an Auth Header to the request. here is the retrieveAuthToken function:

```
retrieveAuthToken(): Promise<string> {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('auth') !== null) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(sessionStorage.getItem('auth'));
            });
        }    

        return this.authService.getAnonToken(); 
    }
```

And the getAnonToken function that this method calls:

```
public getAnonToken(prev?: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.tokens[prev]) {
                resolve({data: this.tokens[prev]});
            }

            if (prev) {
                this.tokens[prev] = prev;
            }

            this.http.post<any>(HttpUrl.AnonToken, {})
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    this.saveAuthToken(response.data);
                    this.tokens[prev] = response.data;

                    this.global.internalAnalytics.getAnonToken();
                    resolve(response.data);
                }, (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });   
        });            
    }]
}
```

Can anyone see why this error may be happening? I have a feeling it is something to do with the return value of the Promise within interceptor function but I cannot be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to return value in any case. In your case , when `retrieveAuthToken` return an error - there is no value returned.

Please return the promise and change the declared returned value.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpBase } from "../http-base";
import { HttpUrl } from "../http-url.enum";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private httpBase: HttpBase
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | Promise<any> {
        if (!this.isMiddleTierRequest(request.url)) {
            return next.handle(request);
        }

        return this.httpBase.retrieveAuthToken()
            .then((token) => {
                const requestWithAuth = request.clone({ 
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }});

                    return next.handle(request);
            });
    }

    private isMiddleTierRequest(url: string): boolean {
        return url.indexOf(HttpUrl.MiddleTier) != -1;
    }
}
```